# How to read folder path from file in Java

Tags: java, windows, directory

Good day, dear colleagues

Mystic! I can not open the network folder. If the String path is hardcoded in the code - everything works fine, but if I read this path string from a file, it is opens My Documents.

1. The string netFolderPath of the path in the file is the same as was simply assigned to the variable before in the code:

`\\\\ello.server\\files\\FD-analysis\\Matherial condition\\`

2. Read in the Main class the public static String netFolderPath variable from file.
3. Next I open the folder, if exists. If not, I create.

````

```
 String fileFolder = Main.netFolderPath + folderName;
    File f = new File(fileFolder);
    if (f.exists()) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer " + fileFolder);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WorkingWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        new File(fileFolder).mkdir();
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer " + fileFolder);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WorkingWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try the ip of the PC the network folder exists on like:

`\\192.168.178.9\your_path_here`

Try a `\\` for a`\` if you use a string as path